# Changing labelling of OpenStreetMap Base Map for ArcGIS Online?

Tags: openstreetmap, labeling, arcgis-online, story-map

I am creating a Story Map and using Open Street Maps as the base map. 
One issue my superiors see is the labeling of the streets. It's way to frequent!

See the attached screenshot:
[image]

Is there a way I can change the frequency of the labeling for the same road?

Comment: No but you can export the osm map  to join line segments together and wait for the raster tiles to be regenerated. This can be within minutes of changes if servers are not busy. but you would need to host he tiles yourself

Comment: I would not encourage to do that generally. It might have been necessary to split them up for one-way-, speed or turn restrictions, or bus relations joining or departing.

Comment: Thanks @Mapperz I was thinking that's the simpliest but I was hoping I missed some kind of ArcGIS functionality that was built in to adjust labels. Andre I work for the Town, there's no buses or anything of the sort. But I am open to alternatives.

Comment: If you know how to edit the data, you can try it. But keep an eye on the tags that might be in one part, and not in the neighbouring part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The background you see are pre-rendered tiles form the Openstreetmap server. You can not easily change them.

You can download the original Openstreetmap data from Geofabrik for your part of the world, and style it for yourself. Either using a local tile creator like `Tilemill`, a single picture with `Maperitive` (which can create tiles as well), or by directly importing the data into your GIS. I don't know what ARCGIS has to offer, but `QGIS` has a direct import tool.